# Exportar Datos Mysql con php

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli, phpmyadmin

saludos, estoy intentando exportar datos mysql hacia un EXCEL usando php,

el problema que tengo es que cuando intento exportar los datos no se exportan, osea muestra los datos en pantalla de nuevo, pero no me da la ventana para exportar..

```
          <?php $output = '';      if(isset($_POST["export_excel"]))  {     $sql = "SELECT * from tblaccounts inner join tblinvoiceitems on tblinvoiceitems.invoiceid=tblaccounts.invoiceid WHERE tblaccounts.date BETWEEN '2015-12-25 0:00:00' AND '2016-09-20 23:59:00'"; $result = mysql_query($sql);


     $output .= '<table>
<tr>
<th>Transaction Date</th>
<th>Invoice Number</th>
<th>User ID</th>
<th>Company Name</th>
<th>Payment Method</th>
<th>Description (Package or Service)</th>
<th>Amount</th>
<th>Tax</th>
<th>Tax Amount</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr>'; 
     while ($r2 = mysql_fetch_array($result)){ echo "<tr>"; echo '<td>'.$r2["duedate"].' </td>'; echo '<td>'.$r2["invoiceid"].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$r2["userid"].'</td>'; $r9 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tblclients WHERE id=$r2[userid]")); echo '<td>'.$r9["companyname"].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$r2["paymentmethod"].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$r2["description"].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$r2["amount"].'</td>'; echo '<td>'.$r2["taxed"].'</td>'; if ($r2["taxed"] == 0 ) { $r3 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbltax WHERE id = $r2[taxed] ")); echo "<td> no tax </td>"; echo '<td>'.$r2["amount"].'</td>';  } else { $r3 = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbltax WHERE id = $r2[taxed] ")); $r6 = $r2["amount"] / $r3["taxrate"]; $r8 = $r6 + $r2["amount"]; echo "<td> $r6 </td>"; echo "<td> $r8 </td>"; } echo " </tr>"; }  $output .= '</table>'; header("Content-Type: application/xls");   header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls");  echo $output;  } ?>
```

Pues el codigo lo saque de aqui: http://webslesson.blogspot.com/2016/02/export-mysql-data-to-excel-in-php-php-tutorial.html

Lo modifique un poco porque estoy usando mysql_query y no mysqli_query ..

¿alguien puede ayudarme?

Answer (score 0):

Reemplaza los headers `header("Content-Type: application/xls"); header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=download.xls");` que hay en el final del código que has compartido con lo siguiente:

```
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='download.xls');
```

Es lo que se recomienda en la [documentación de PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) para forzar que se descargue y no se muestre el contenido de un archivo.

Por cierto, en realidad lo que estás haciendo es exportar un documento con una tabla HTML que se guarda con la extensión XLS y que además misteriosamente Excel importa correctamente. Pero como no era tu pregunta, pues me limito únicamente a decir esto.

Saludos :-)